# Slight troubles with WordCloud module - TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'relative_scaling'

Tags: python

Wrote this simple little script to create a wordcloud from a transcript of the Benghazi hearing today, but it's getting hung up on an error I don't really understand.

```
from os import path
from wordcloud import WordCloud

d = path.dirname(__file__)

# Read the whole text.
text = open(path.join(d, 'clintonSpeech.txt')).read()

# Generate a word cloud image
wordcloud = WordCloud().generate(text)

# Display the generated image:
# the matplotlib way:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(wordcloud)
plt.axis("off")

# take relative word frequencies into account, lower max_font_size
wordcloud = WordCloud(max_font_size=40, relative_scaling=.5).generate(text)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(wordcloud)
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

Traceback:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wordCloud.py", line 19, in <module>
    wordcloud = WordCloud(max_font_size=40, relative_scaling=.5).generate(text)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'relative_scaling'`

Comment: What version are you using? `relative_scaling` was [added in August](https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/commit/9aaf533788b1611bfd8b991e89f511d37ee7a886#diff-1bbef89eafda5ae684278c68e8f3c3c7R137), but version [`1.1.3`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wordcloud/1.1.3) was released on `2015-07-22`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To fix this, change

```
 wordcloud = WordCloud(max_font_size=40, relative_scaling=.5).generate(text)
```

to

```
 wordcloud = WordCloud(max_font_size=40).generate(text)
```

Figured it out as I was typing this up, but will leave it up as maybe someone else will have the same problem.